# How to avoid these duplications and streamline?

Tags: software-development, code, agile

I working in a departmentA, where I write my own code and perform required task. Some other departmentB is working on the same area (departmentB is not aware that departmentA already completed) which I already worked on. Most importantly multiple departments across the organisation performed tasks which are common across them, for which each product team was writing their separate code. Thus, there are some redundant efforts being performed across teams.

This could be because of a communication gap. I would like to avoid this kind of duplication and reuse. And going further to make it better organised. How to avoid these duplications and streamline, aligning all to the same?

1. What do you think the problem is here?
2. How can it be better handled?
3. Is agile the only solution?
4. Any better approaches to avoid these kind of conflicts?
   Can you please help me here?
5. How coding structure/repo is to be maintained if at all to be re-used?

Comment: Reduce the communication gap.

Comment: @SolarMike How do we make it better by reducing these duplications ? This should not stop any ongoing activities and should be streamlined further also.

Comment: @SolarMike Do you see any ideas ?

Comment: Yes, the answer gives you some ideas...

Comment: @Fresher seems like you have too many questions cramped together (the only probability for downvote from someone). I think you have identified the issue correctly as lack of communication and proper planning. Hence, I suggest you ask one question that is on point to resolve the issue like "What are the best practices that can be applied in such cases?" but a lot of answers to this would be subjective and depend on various factors like "how open 'others' are to changes suggested, etc"

Answer (score 2):

This is really a communication issue.

This is one of those cases where you should have something like instant messaging channels for certain topics, and before you start work on some sort of area, you ask if anyone has already tackled the problem or is going to.

As you build experience within a company, you begin to understand that there are subject matter experts out there, who are usually across what happens in certain areas. Even if informal, it would be polite to give them a heads up about what you're working on. They may have opinions on the matter. They may even direct you to someone else who is already tackling it.

Something like stand-ups, even just general communication within the team, is usually enough to share enough information around who may be experts worth talking to.

More formally, you should be using some sort of work queue system, and before working on something, you should look for similar tickets. Maybe by spending 5% of extra effort generalising your solution, you can make something suitable for a wider variety of users within the org.

If your departments are silo'd to the point where you have no capacity to know what fellow workers are working on in different departments, you're really relying on senior management to identified where there may be shared effort.

Comment: Thanks Gregory. I got your point. Do you see any idea, where can start sharing or restructuring code so that to avoid duplications ?

Comment: Or any best practices ? What model can we implement to overcome these kind of communication issue ?

Comment: Gregory, any updates ?

Comment: What is your role in the organisation?

Comment: Fresher. It would be great if you can help or show your experienced knowledge.

Comment: Was is a fresher? I'm guessing freshman software developer, given your question is tagged as software development? If you're asking software, well, presumably you've got an education in software development, so you should be thinking about source control to share scripts. If you don't have source control (!?), any form of CMS is better than nothing. It would be very difficult for a junior software developer to inspire changes here, but to be honest, it's not your problem. Wasted effort is a managerial problem.